# Java 8 Optional to do null check in hierarchical objects

Tags: java, object, java-8, java-stream, option-type

Using Optional to Null Check While Object Cloning different type of object.

```
class A{ C cObj; List<B> bList;}

class B{ C cObj; List<C> cList;}

class C { String label; String value;}

class D{ String name; String age; String addressCode;}
```

Mapping A -> D

```
d.setAddessCode(A.getBlist().get(0).getcList().get(0).getValue());
```

How can check null using java 8 optional

```
A.getBlist().get(0).getcList().get(0).getValue()
```

I tried

```
d.setAddessCode(Optional.ofNullable(A).map(A::getBList).map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty).findFirst().map(B::getCList).map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty).findFirst().map(C::getValue).orElse(null)));
```

How can i check null in List and value together.

Comment: How do you get from C to D?

Comment: `orElseGet(Stream::empty)` from B should already be doing that for you, isn't it?

Comment: Why only null-check? What if `bList` is non-null but empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use Streams. Here is code with both null and empty checks:

```java
d.setAddressCode(Optional.ofNullable(a)
                         .map(A::getbList)
                         .filter(bList -> ! bList.isEmpty())
                         .map(bList -> bList.get(0))
                         .map(B::getcList)
                         .filter(cList -> ! cList.isEmpty())
                         .map(cList -> cList.get(0))
                         .map(C::getValue)
                         .orElse(null));
```

That can be simplified with a little helper method:

```java
public class MyUtils {
    public static <E> E getFirst(List<E> list) {
        return (list == null || list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0));
    }
}
```

```java
d.setAddressCode(Optional.ofNullable(a)
                         .map(A::getbList)
                         .map(MyUtils::getFirst)
                         .map(B::getcList)
                         .map(MyUtils::getFirst)
                         .map(C::getValue)
                         .orElse(null));
```

Comment: What if the first element in the list is `null`?

Comment: @LukeLee Then `addressCode` will be `null`.

Comment: @LukeLee You *think*? Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)? If you did, you'd *know* whether it causes NPE or not.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood. :)

Comment: For a moment I thought, oh, that's NPE. Then I realise it's not.

Comment: Why are you doing that redundant `list == null`-check in `getFirst`? Isn’t the whole point to get rid of explicit `null`-checks?

Comment: @Holger It's a utility method. It can be used in multiple ways. You're right, when used from an `Optional`, it'll never see a null value. The null check is standard defensive programming.